# c# button calling several methods

Tags: c#

I am working on an app that will do a browser search across several search engines. I am currently setting up the interface and this is my code:

```
namespace OIT
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void TestButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process proc = new();
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "https://google.ca/search?q=" + GoogleTextBox.Text;
            proc.Start();
        }


        public void DuckDuckGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process proc = new();
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + DDGTextBox.Text;
            proc.Start();
        }

        private void SearchAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GoogleTextBox.Text + DDGTextBox.Text == "") 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter search terms.");
            }
            else
            {
                TestButton();
                DuckDuckGo_Click();
            }
          
        }

    }
}
```

The issue is the `testbutton()` and `duckduckgo_click();` methods at the button are causing argument errors:

> Error CS7036
> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender' of 'Form1.TestButton(object, EventArgs)'

Anyone able to help me out with this? I'm sure it's a super simple fix but I've done through all the similar questions and I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the code of each button in a separate function. Then call these functions from the button click handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the arguments of the SearchAll_Click method to TestButton and DuckDuckGo_Click methods.

```
private void SearchAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GoogleTextBox.Text + DDGTextBox.Text == "") 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter search terms.");
    }
    else
    {
        TestButton(sender,e);
        DuckDuckGo_Click(sender,e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Brad - Your code is broken. Even though this answers your question it doesn't fix the brokenness of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few broken parts to it.

First up, you need to pass both `object sender` & `EventArgs e` when you call `TestButton` & `DuckDuckGo_Click`, and you can easily do that with the following:

```
TestButton(sender, e);
DuckDuckGo_Click(sender, e);
```

However, in doing that you force your code to run the code in the handler for both of those buttons.

So let's say you decided to put some validation code in the two other button handlers. Like this:

```
public void DuckDuckGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DDGTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a search term.");
    }
    else
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + DDGTextBox.Text;
        proc.Start();
    }
}
```

Now your code would throw up three message boxes if the user didn't enter any search terms and they clicked the `SearchAll` button.

Instead it's best to separate the click handlers from the code that executes the searches.

It's also best to not repeat yourself where possible.

Here's how.

Start with one method to start the search process:

```
private void StartSearch(string url_template, string search)
{
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = String.Format(url_template, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(search))
    proc.Start();
}
```

Note that I've introduced `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` to ensure that you don't create an illegal URL from the user input.

Now you can have two helper methods to launch each search:

```
private void StartGoogleSearch(string search)
{
    StartSearch("https://google.ca/search?q=", search);
}

private void StartDuckDuckGoSearch(string search)
{
    StartSearch("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=", search);
}
```

Now you're just left with the three click handlers:

```
private void TestButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GoogleTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter search term.");
    }
    else
    {
        StartGoogleSearch(GoogleTextBox.Text);
    }
}


private void DuckDuckGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DDGTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter search term.");
    }
    else
    {
        StartDuckDuckGoSearch(DDGTextBox.Text);
    }
}

private void SearchAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GoogleTextBox.Text == "" || DDGTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter both search terms.");
    }
    else
    {
        StartGoogleSearch(GoogleTextBox.Text);
        StartDuckDuckGoSearch(DDGTextBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Note the `if` in the last one correctly check for either term being blank, not just the aggregate. Your existing code was broken in that it would launch both searches if you had typed text in one box only.

---

Having said all of that, if you asked me how I would write this, it'd probably be more like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _engines = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "Google", "https://google.ca/search?q=" },
    { "DuckDuckGo", "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" },
}

private void TestButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartSearch("Google");
}

private void DuckDuckGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartSearch("DuckDuckGo");
}

private void SearchAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartSearch("Google", "DuckDuckGo");
}

private void StartSearch(params string[] engines)
{
    if (SearchTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a search term.");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var engine in engines)
        {
            if (_engines.ContainsKey(engine))
            {
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = String.Format(_engines[engine], HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SearchTextBox.Text))
                proc.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is only one search term box, but now you can easily add multiple search engines.